# C# List<> vs Dictionary<> in runtime collection istantiation

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, generics

I have to dynamically create a collection with type using reflection (type is provided as variable) so basically i am doing something like that :

```
Type actualListType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(listType);
IList = (IList )Activator.CreateInstance(actualListType );
```

Everything work fine, but if i try to do the same thing for the dictionary i get an error :

```
Type actualDictionaryType = typeof(Dictionary<>).MakeGenericType(keyType, valueType);
```

I get the error CS0305 :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0305?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0305)

Is not clear what i am missing here.
I am working in Visual Studio 2019, with .Net Framework 4.8

Comment: The generic type definition is `typeof(Dictionary<,>)` (note the comma). That's why it's giving CS0305 Using the generic type 'generic type' requires 'number' type arguments, which I'm guessing is filled in with `Dictionary` and `2`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey wow really embarassed, sorry i didn't notieced, and i was thinking there was a special behaviour of dictionary..what a dumb blunder indeed

Comment: @Skary more caffeine is sometimes required before evaluating errors 